# H2 database not known to support REF_CURSOR parameters

Tags: java, h2db

I'm working on Oracle stored procedure, I have procedure and 1 parameter

```
in - > x IN VARCHAR2, out -> REF_CURSOR in out SYS_REFCURSOR.
```

I'm trying to call this procedure using hibernate, but i have exception

I need the same but H2 database memory

But this error appears:

```
[org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] not known to support REF_CURSOR parameters
```

This my code to create procedure:

```
DROP ALIAS IF EXISTS LOGPROCESSOR;
CREATE ALIAS LOGPROCESSOR AS $$
@CODE
java.sql.ResultSet getTableContent(java.sql.Connection con, final String cv_1) throws Exception {
    String resultValue=null;
    java.sql.ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(
    "SELECT IDTLOG,DATE,IDSTORE,INIUPLOAD,RECEIVED,PENDING,VALIDATED FROM LOGPROCESSOR_GETSTATUSREPORT");
       /*while(rs.next())
       {
        resultValue=rs.getString(1);
       }
    return resultValue;*/
    return rs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Hibernate H2Dialect does not yet support stored procedures with REF_CURSOR result sets, so it isn't possible at this time.

The [H2Dialect](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/H2Dialect.java#L51) extends the base Dialect class but does not implement the [getCallableStatement](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.java#L2841:2844) method

```
public CallableStatementSupport getCallableStatementSupport() {
    // most databases do not support returning cursors (ref_cursor)...
    return StandardCallableStatementSupport.NO_REF_CURSOR_INSTANCE;
}
```